# how do I get a Quicktime video window to play on an external monitor, simultaneously using the laptop for something else?

Tags: macbook-pro, display, mediaplayer

Using Macbook using OS-X 10.5.8, how do I get a Quicktime video window to play on an external monitor, simultaneously using the laptop for something else?

I have a Macbook circa 2008 which has OS-x 10.5.8.  I recently installed an HDTV in order to watch videos from the Macbook on a larger screen, while continuing to use the laptop for other things. I am unable to play a video on the larger screen unless in the mirror arrangement of the screens.  With a side-by-side arrangement,  I can drag the folder which contains the movie, but when I click on open, it opens and plays on the Macbook instead of on the tv.  Other folders also open in the laptop window, not the tv.

http://uk.answers.yahoo.com/question/index?qid=20080914024038AA5ivCZ

This suggestion of dragging the window doesn't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Quicktime Player, go to Preferences. Under "Full Screen", there is a picture of your screens similar to the Displays pane of System Preferences. If you click on a screen, a picture of the QT Player logo will be overlaid on that screen. The screen that has the logo is the active screen for Full Screen Mode.

EDIT: I don't know if you can still do other things while QT Player is full screen.

Comment: This worked somewhat, but I had to reduce the screen size and then drag it to the tv and resize it to full screen.  The laptop can continue to work, but it reduces the size of the video image again. At least it's in the tv.